# Mongoose aggregation issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create an API endpoint that returns a count of order items that have a status of omitted.

Here is my model..

```
const defectsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "defectId": String,
    "defectLoggedDate": String,
    "custId": String,
    "defectTitle": String,
    "defectDesc": String,
    "defectStatus": String,
    "defectRequestor": String,
    "defectCustRef": String,
    "defectPriority": String,
    "defectCreator": String,
    "defectAssignedOperative": String,
    "defectAssignedOperativeEmail": String,
    "defectAwaitingVar": Boolean,
    "defectRcvdDate": Date,
    "defectDueDate": Date,
    "defectEstimatedDuration": String,
    "defectPlannedStartDate": Date,
    "defectPlannedStartTime": String,
    "defectPlannedEndTime": String,
    "defectCompleteDate": Date,
    "defectVatRate": String,
    "covidOnhold": String,
    "defectTags": [
        {
        "defectTagShortName": String
        }
    ], 
    "defectItems": [
        {
        "defectItemId": String,
        "defectItemCode": String,
        "defectItemLocation": String,
        "defectItemQuantity": String,
        "defectItemUnit": String,
        "defectItemCost": String,
        "defectItemLongDescription": String,
        "defectItemShortDescription": String,
        "defectItemCat": String,
        "defectItemSubCat": String,
        "defectItemRate": String,
        "defectItemStatus": String,
        "defectItemVarFlag": Boolean,
        "defectItemAssignedOperative": String,
        "defectItemCustNotes": String,
        "defectItemDjcsNotes": String
        }
    ], 
    "defectCustAddress1": String,
    "defectCustAddress2": String,
    "defectCustCity": String,
    "defectCustCounty": String,
    "defectCustPostcode": String,
    "defectCustPhone": String,
    "defectCustEmail": String,
    "defectCustName": String,
    "defectCat": String,
    "defectImages": [
        {
            "defectImageUrl": String
        }
    ],
    "defectValue": String,
    "defectNotes": [
        {
            "defectNoteId": String,
            "defectNoteCategory": String,
            "defectNoteReminderEnabled": String,
            "defectNoteStatus": String,
            "defectNoteReminderDate": String,
            "defectNoteText": String,
            "defectNoteAuthor": String,
            "defectNoteCreateDate": Date
        }
    ],
    "defectTasks": [
        {
            "defectTaskStage": String,
            "defectTaskDescription": String,
            "defectTaskStatus": String,
            "defectTaskDetails": String,
            "defectTaskActionDatetime": Date,
            "defectTaskActionExector": String,
            "defectTaskIncompleteDescription": String,
            "defectTaskCompletedDescription": String,
            "defectActiveTask": String,
            "defectTaskAttendDate": Date,
            "defectTaskAttendTime": String,
            "defectTaskNotes001": String,
            "defectTaskNotes002": String,
            "defectTaskNotes003": String,
            "defectTaskNotes004": String,
            "defectTaskAttendReturnVisitDate": Date,
            "defectTaskAttendReturnVisitTime": String,
            "defectAdditionalLabourFlag": String,
            "defectReportSubmitted": String,
            "defectCostsApproved": String 
        }
    ],
    "returnVisits": [
        {
            "returnVisitId": String,
            "returnVisitReason": String
        }
    ]
});
```

And here is the code I am using to try and return the count and defectId...

```
// Get count of omitted items per order
app.get('/v1/itemsomitted/:id', async(request, response) => {
    try {
        var result = await defectsModel.aggregate([{ $match: { defectId: request.params.id } },
            { $unwind: "$defectItems" },
            { $match: {"defectItems.defectItemStatus": "omitted"} },
            { $group: {
                "_id": {
                    "_id": "$_id",
                    "status": "$defectItems.defectItemStatus"
                },
                "count": { "$sum": 1 }
            }},
            {$project: {defectId: 1, count: 2} }
        ]).exec(function(err, count){
            response.json(count);
        })
    } catch (error) {
        response.status(500).send(error);
    }
});
```

When I hit the API endpoint, I get no response. I'm using Mongo Atlas and have used the UI provided in Atlas to test the aggregation pipeline which works fine there.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just to confirm as it may be a little unclear from my post. I do get an API response (200) but it's empty

Comment: `  {$project: {defectId: 1, count: 2} }` check this line.  there wouldn't be defectId field and why count project values is 2?

Comment: Did you console log `result`?